# AWS CLI - result using jmespath query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath, aws-shell

I've a problem so you will safe my life :-)

when I run the following command from aws-shell

```
cloudformation describe-stacks --query Stacks[*].[StackName,StackId,CreationTime,LastUpdatedTime,Parameters[?ParameterKey==\`PARAM_NAME1\`].ParameterValue,Parameters[?ParameterKey==\`PARAM_NAME2\`].ParameterValue] --output text
```

the result is splitted on 3 rows:

> automation-X  arn:aws:cloudformation:X    X   None
>   PARAM_VALUE1
>   PARAM_VALUE2

but my goal is to have only one row (like this)

> automation-X  arn:aws:cloudformation:X    X   None        PARAM_VALUE1    PARAM_VALUE2

that is, having PARAM_VALUE1 and PARAM_VALUE2 on the first and only line.

can anyone help me?

I appreciate it,
thank you in advance

I forgot to indicate that the result of the command are many lines (more than 1000) and each line is composed of 6 parameters

Comment: Why don't you try  "| tr -d '\n'"

Comment: thank you @sashok_bg unfortunately it does not work .... it writes everything on a single line :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
Parameters[?ParameterKey==`PARAM_VALUE1`].ParameterValue
```

returns a projection that itself returns an **array** of `ParameterValue`s. Even though that array only contains one item, the `aws --output text` mode still interprets it as a new line. To fix this, you need to convert the projection into a single value using a pipe `|` to stop the projection, then choose the first item in the array:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --query 'Stacks[*].[StackName,StackId,CreationTime,LastUpdatedTime,Parameters[?ParameterKey==`PARAM_NAME1`].ParameterValue|[0],Parameters[?ParameterKey==`PARAM_NAME2`].ParameterValue|[0]]' --output text
```

You'll see the `|[0]` added to each parameter in the query.